# Multiple Imputation Chained Equations for categorical and continuous data

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, r-mice

I am trying to find comprehensive resources for MICE in python that perform similarly to R's implementation, which is modeled on [Van Burren's text](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/).

Looking at the [scikit learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html#sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer), as well as stats models, it appears that both of these methods do NOT allow one to specify a fully conditional distribution for a variable conditional on others (nor do they allow you to specify the structure of the data (i.e, iterative imputer doesn't treat indicator columns vs continuous variables differently; you cannot specify different models for imputation for variable type).  This is problematic, as any predictions (and any inferences you make) will be highly biased as a result for mixed datatypes (or just non interpretable).